# What is the difference between PRIMARY KEY and CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY?

Tags: mysql

I'm using MySQL and I am wondering what the difference is between this:

```
CREATE TABLE Employees(
E_Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
);
```

and:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEES(
E_Id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
CONSTRAINT pk_Employee PRIMARY KEY(E_Id));
```

Are they the same?

Comment: No, they're not the same. `ALTER TABLE` is used to alter a table, `CONSTRAINT` is used to add a foreign constraint (enforcing referential integrity) to a column.

Comment: Where is `ALTER TABLE` in your question?

Comment: I edited my question, alter table wasn't needed....i'm just wondering what CONSTRAINT does compared to my 1st example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think both primary key definitions are identical.

See my [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6ee6d/2).

and output from show create table Employes_1 und _2:

> Employees_1 | CREATE TABLE `employees_1` (   `E_Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   PRIMARY KEY (`E_Id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
>
> Employees_2 | CREATE TABLE `employees_2` (   `E_Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   PRIMARY KEY (`E_Id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

For the answer if the table name `Employees` is equal to `EMPLOYEES` refer to system variable [lower_case_table_names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lower_case_table_names).

Comment: Ah, because you said: "I think no" on my question "Are they the same". Must of misread...they are the same i reckon....